# MVC5 There was an error getting the type

Tags: c#, database

I am working on a MVC 5 project. But when I click `add view`, I get an error as mentioned below:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: There was an
>   error getting the type 'MVCdeneme.UYELER'. Try rebuilding the project.

`UYELER` is database table.

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild? Also restart visual studio and see if the problem persists.

Comment: are you using code fluent for your dbcontext?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have made your image inline.

Answer (score -1):

For this problem, you need to rebuild your project, and then create the controller.